# jQuery - Style by occurrence order of an element inside of another element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's my problem.

**HTML**

```
    <ul id="content">
      <li id="item1">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li id="menu-item1">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>........</li></ul></li>
....................................................
          <li id="menu-item10">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li>........</li></ul></li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>
```

How can I change css top of each ul#sub-menu by following?

```
1-sub menu top: -8px
2-sub menu top: -40px
3-sub menu top: -72px
step = -32px
and so on ...
10-sub menu top: - ###px
```

Sorry guys I found my syntax mistake .... here is my code. I will appreciate if you have better one ;)

```
$('ul.sub-menu').each( function() {
    $(this).css('top', (-8 + $(this).index('ul.sub-menu') * -32));
});
```

Comment: ID of an element must be unique... so use `sub-menu` as class

Comment: @ArunPJohny .. sorry for that, but actually in my website they are classes ;)

Comment: try `var $subs = $('#content .sub-menu');
$subs.css('top', function (i) {
    return -(8 + (i * 32))
})`

Comment: can you give a more details markup sample with the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LLyxq0g3/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use following function in document ready method, like

```
jQuery('ul#content ul[id=sub-menu]').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).css('top', jQuery('>li',jQuery(this).parent().parent()).index(jQuery(this).parent())*-32-8)
});
```

Note: Its complex but working fine, check here http://jsfiddle.net/siddhapura/reud3Lre/

Answer (score 1):

Try this it is not exactly like you wanted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/0ocsau3p/1/)

```
var len = $('ul').length;
var top = 1;
$('.sub-menu').each(function () {


$(this).css({
    top: top
})
top = top + top +8
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is how it can be done with CSS:

```css
ul#menu{
    margin-top:-24px;
}
ul#sub-menu{
    margin-top:32px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
        <li id="menu-item1">
            <ul id="sub-menu">
                <li>........</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li id="menu-item2">
            <ul id="sub-menu">
                <li>........</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    
        <li id="menu-item3">
            <ul id="sub-menu">
                <li>........</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
 </ul>
```